# Real solution of differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to self-learn differential equations. The book I'm following is "A First Course in Differential Equations with Applications", Dennis G. Zill.

In the first chapter he writes:

**The first order differential equations**
$$
{\left ( \frac{dy}{dx} \right )}^2+1=0
$$
**and**
$$
\left ( y' \right )^2+y^2+4=0
$$

**possess no real solutions. Why?**

I undertand the concept of solution, but I haven't found in the text an explanation of what a real solution is

Comment: Do the equations $x^2 + 1 = 0$ or $x^2 + y^2 + 4 = 0$ have any real solutions (either in $x$ or $(x,y)$ respectively)?

Comment: real as in not complex

Comment: so it means that the solution is a real function?

Comment: Yes, "real solution" means the solution should be a real valued function.